# Where does the centripetal force come from? How to calculate?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, free-body-diagram, centripetal-force

When a bucket filled with water rotates, the water surface will be parabolic( I mean the water is rotating and the water surface is parabolic). Where does the centripetal force of a particle of water come from? From horizontal thrust? Or does it come from the water level difference? How to calculate?

[image: Left-right pressure difference]

As shown in the figure, the paraboloid formed by the rotation of water in the bucket. Because the water level at the left end of the cube (red box) is low, and the water level at the right end is high, h < H, there is a pressure difference. This pressure difference provides the centripetal force of the motion of the cube. This is my explanation. Am I correct?

Comment: Assuming you mean, the bucket is facing upward, sitting on a turntable, rotating on a vertical axis? And also, that the water is not moving with respect to the bucket itself?

Comment: Every molecule follows circular path, but inertia makes it _want_ to follow the tangent line. Most of them are forced to follow the circular path because their neighbors get in the way of them following the straight line.  The ones at the very edge are stopped from following straight lines because the walls of the bucket get in the way. I don't know the proper way to state the answer, but it probably includes the words "Normal Force."

Comment: @gented Centripetal force is not a fictitious force, centrifugal is.

Comment: Ooops I misread the question, you're right, ignore my comment :)

Comment: @SolomonSlow I mean the water is rotating and the water surface is parabolic.

Comment: @SRS Centrifugal force is the imaginary force.

Comment: @enbinzheng I did not say that it's a real force? Did I?

Comment: @SRS I'm sure your answer is that centripetal force is the real force.

Comment: What is wrong with the answer given so far?

Answer (score 0):

A particle at the surface of the water experiences two forces. Once is the force of gravity which acts vertically downwards. The other is the buoyancy force from the surrounding water, which acts perpendicular to the surface of the water. If the buoyancy force is $B$ and the water surface is at an angle $\theta$ to the horizontal then we can resolve forces horizontally and vertically to get

$F_h = B \sin \theta \\
F_v = B \cos \theta - mg$

The net vertical force must be zero, so we have

$B \cos \theta = mg \\ \Rightarrow F_h = mg \tan \theta$

The net horizontal force is the centripetal force. This comes from the horizontal component of the buoyancy force. If we assume all particles at the surface of the water are travelling in horizontal circles then the centripetal force will depend on the mass $m$ of the particle, the radius $r$ of the horizontal circle in which the particle is travelling and the angule velocity $\omega$. So

$mg\tan \theta = mr\omega^2 \\ \Rightarrow \tan \theta = \frac{r\omega^2}{g}$

If we assume all particles have the same angular velocity the $\tan \theta$ is proportional to $r$. For particles near the centre of the  bucket $r$ and $\theta$ are small. As you move further away from the centre of the bucket $r$ increases and so $\theta$ must also increase.

Comment: @AaronStevens Not al all. If the surface of the water at distance $r$ from the centre is at height $h(r)$ above the centre then $\frac{dh}{dr}=\tan \theta = \frac{r \omega^2}{g}$. Solve for $h(r)$ and you get a paraboloid.

Comment: @AaronStevens Ok, so the centripetal force is the horizontal component of the buoyancy force.  I have made an edit to my answer to state this explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

See, a free surface of a fluid (here a liquid) is a surface of constant pressure. This is so because fluids cannot bear any tangential stress.
According to your question, I'll assume the fluid tube rotates about a vertical axis and does not translate.
I'll define the co-ordinate axes as the following and take two points on the surface, A and B.
[image]

As I have mentioned, the pressure at both A and B must be the same, as both lie on the fluid surface.

Note : This is only a 2D view of the surface, a 3-dimensional argument will give a paraboloid shape.

Let this have a density of $\rho$.
Now, you should note that in a rotating fluid, an excess pressure is developed in the direction perpendicular to the angular velocity, $\omega$.
This pressure mainly comes from the thrust from neighbouring molecules. One can easily reason that a molecule by itself would follow a tangential path had not the surrounding molecules constrained it to move in a circular path. This creates a $∆P$.
To see how, consider an element of length $dx$ along a cylindrical part of the rotating fluid, which is at a distance $x$ from the other end (the centre of rotation).

[image]

The net force on this element is $$F = SdP$$
This force is the centripetal force which rotates this element along a radius $x$
Hence [image]
Integrating the expressions, $$\int_0^P dP$$ = $$\int_0^x \rho\omega^2 xdx$$
Thus $$P = \frac{\rho\omega^2 x^2}{2}$$
Now, going back to the original problem, as in the figure a horizontal distance of $x$ gives an excess pressure of $$\frac{\rho\omega^2 x^2}{2}$$ while an vertical elevation of $y$ decreases pressure by $y\rho g$.
Equating these two, $$ y = \frac{\omega^2 x^2}{2g}$$
which is the equation of a parabola.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the radial pressure gradient provides the centripetal force.